# Trying to call an array of arguments on a function

Tags: php, oop

I have an array of arguments to pass to a method where the number of arguments is variable. I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

```
class Entity {
    protected $realObject;

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        // just call this method on the $property, otherwise redefine the method
        // error_log("Called $name");

        // TODO support variable numbers of arguments
        $argc = count($arguments);
        if($argc > 0) {
            return $this->realObject->$name($arguments[0]);
        } else {
            return $this->realObject->$name();
        }
    }

}
```

I've been looking at all sorts of ways of doing it, but can't seem to work out a way of turning an array into a variable of variables.

Comment: and the first parameter you pass to `_call` method is always a property of `$this->realObject`? Is `realObject` a class instance you inject on the constructor of Entity?

Comment: Yes, it's an abstraction of somebody else's classes. My object is a copy of their object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [built-in support for this in PHP >= 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) (which you should be running at the very least).

E.g.:

```
$parameters = ['parameter1', 'parameter2', 'parameter3'];

function iAcceptManyParameters(...$parameters) {
   foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
      echo $parameter, "\n";
   }
}

iAcceptManyParameters(...$parameters);
```

You can see it working [here](https://repl.it/GWZk/1).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Just adding three dots has solved it, who'd have thought!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

```
class Entity
{
    protected $myClass;

    public function __construct(string $myClass)
    {
        $this->myClass = new $myClass;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->myClass->$name($arguments);
    }
}

class TestClass
{
    public function foo($msg)
    {
        return $msg;
    }
}

$entity = new Entity('TestClass');
var_dump($entity->foo('bar', 'baz'));
die();
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "baz"
}
```

But based on your comment: `Yes, it's an abstraction of somebody else's classes. My object is a copy of their object`, why don't you just create your class, which extends their class? e.g `class MyEntity extends TheirEntity {...}`. Your class will then inherit their public and protected properties & methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you see, magic method `__call`  of a class is called when you try to execute a method of said class you don't have access to. So, in this case:

```
class Entity {

    protected function realObject($a, $b, $c) {

    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {

        $argc = count($arguments);

        if($argc > 0) {
            return $this->$name($arguments[0],$arguments[1],$arguments[2]);
        } else {
            return $this->$name();
        }
    }

}
```

Now, let's say you instance this class and try to call a private method

```
$myEntity = new Entity();

$myEntity->realObject('hello','my','friends');
```

The protected method invocation is intercepted by `__call`, so it's like you had called

```
$myEntity->__call('realObject',['hello','my','friends']);
```

Whatever you decide to do inside your `__call` method, that is up to you. In my example, it just forwards your call to the protected method.